# Extracting distances of coordinates to different land use types from a raster

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, terra

I am trying to extract the distance from a range of coordinates to land use types. So the end goal would be a range of columns with the distance to water, crops, building etc for each coordinate

The land use data is taken from SENTINEL-2 10M LAND USE/LAND COVER DOWNLOAD. I have two rasters that I have had to merge together to get the full study area.

I also have created a raster which is a box with a 10km buffer around the study area.

Finally, I have the coordinates of the households that I am extracting data from.

The code that I have tried is as follows...

```
#read in dataframe with household coordinates
df <- import('clean_R/clean_gps.csv') # Read data

#read in study area shp and extent 
extent <- rast("data/areas/extent.tif")
extent <- project(extent, "EPSG:32628")

#read in points of households 
points <- st_read('data/points/points.shp') 

## Prep 2020 LU 
lu_20a <- rast("2020/28P_20200101-20210101.tif") #Import land use 
lu_20b <- rast("2020/28Q_20200101-20210101.tif") #Import land use 
lu_20a <- project(lu_20a, "EPSG:32628") #reproject raster
lu_20b <- project(lu_20b, "EPSG:32628") #reproject raster
lu_20 <- merge(lu_20a, lu_20b) #Merge two rasters
plot(lu_20) #Check raster areas
plot(st_geometry(study_area), col = "dark sea green", add =TRUE) # outline of Somali
crs(lu_20)  #Check crs of areas

remask = resample(lu_20, extent) #ensure rasters have same coordinates 
lu_20_2 <- crop(lu_20, remask)  #Crop to raster_area
plot(lu_20_2)

#water_20
water20 <- lu_20  #create new raster for analysis which will extract just water data, water is classified as 1
coltab(water20)
water20[water20>1] <- NA # extract only water values - WATER = 1 
water20[water20<1] <- NA # extract only water values - WATER = 1 
water20[water20 == 0] <- NA # extract only water values - WATER = 1 

plot(water20) #Checl that only water is present 
water20_dis <- distance(water20) #Extract distance of every pixel to closest water
df$lu20_water_points <- extract(water20_dis, points) #Extract distance for each coordinate


However, I have tried multiple different options and the latest issue is:
[distance] unknown extent
```

However, I have tried multiple different options and the latest issue I had was that I get a warning:

[distance] unknown extent

This is occurs when extracting terra:distance.

Any solutions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you `plot(water20_dis)` to check whether the raster looks like you expect it to look like, and add `points(points)` or compare CRS to see whether raster and points indeed share the same projection?

Comment: Yes, I checked and they are all of the same CRS.